# can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\Office' while trying to run a package installed with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

the command I run on cmd to start the package:-

```
localstack start
```

The error message I get:-

```
can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\Office'
```

Now I dont understand why it is looking for `__main__` at `'C:\\Users\\Office'` when the path to python in my system is `C:\Users\Office User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

It seems like it is breaking because of the whitespace in the username `Office user`

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What does the command `which localstack` return ?

Comment: @jusstol C:\Users\Office user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\Office'

Comment: did you try to run the following command : `which localstack`

Comment: @jusstol just tried, it says, `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command`